# Is there a way in python to name a list, dictionary, string, tuple or other data type using variables?

Tags: python, list, variables, dictionary, types

I have a list of 127716 lists. Characters, numerics ect.  This length will vary with other lists I will use  later.  The values are in order so that they are in similar groups of 1435 lists.  They in turn will form 10-11 groups of 5-12 groups of lists.  I want to be able  to separate the groups and access them by variables taken from the the third and  forth lists, i.e. l[2] and l[3] of each group. They will look like this.  Example: x(1,1), x(1,2),...,x(1,8), x(2,1), x(2,2),...,x(2,12),......x(11,1), ...,x(11,6)
I use python 3.6.3 and visual studio code    I am obviously a beginner  I 
have looked  thru all the tutorials I can find and tried to search stackoverflow, but can find no  questions that answer my problem.  I am trying to rewrite a basic program I wrote 35  years ago, or maybe 40. I can create a dictionary of a group, but only one without being able to use variables in the dictionary names.  Is there a way in python to name a list, dictionary, string,  tuple or other data type using variables?

I hope this is the way to respond to queries.

The third and  forth lists, i.e. l[2] and l[3] of each group are identifying numbers.  They 
are integers, from 1-12 usually, and they make the best identifiers of the 1435 unit groups. They are unique to each group and can be used to separate and identify the groups. That is why I want to use them as variables to name whatever data type I can find.

here is a sample of the list
['"EMD"', '"20170820"', '1', '1', '', '870', '"D"', '', '"N"', '"BUN"', '"Ch15k"', '15000', '', '', '45.79', '""', '"H"', '""', '""', '"EMD"', '1', '"QH"', '9', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '22', '1', '1', '0', '"LORENZOJMARQUEZ"', ...................................
 '"EMD"', '"20170820"', '1', '2',..........
['"EMD"', '"20170820"', '1', '3',................

....................................['"EMD"', '"20170820"', '11', '8']

```
d = {}
a = {}
i,j = 0,0
for x in range(0,len(L)-1):
    a={(l[i+2],l[i+3]):{'trail':l[0+i], 'date':l[i+1], 'number': l[i+2], 'position':l[i+3],........

    # I break the group down again to about 76 lists per each 1435 group here and try to start a 
    # dictionary but need to create dictionaries within a dictionary using my identifiers as the
    # dictionary name.

    z = (int(l[i+2]),int(l[i+3]))
    d = [z] = {(str(a))}
    i=i + 1435
```

Comment: you just say `var = [data]` ???

Comment: Can you give a small, concrete example of your list-of-lists? Likely, there are better approaches using either built-in data structures (i.e. dictionaries) or maybe a class.

Comment: This question is confusing. When you say "access them by variables taken from the third and forth lists" you mean that you want to do a search on the main list and return the specific data?

Comment: I edited my question to try and give an example of my list and yes I want to use the variables for 'number' and 'position' to name a dictionary or something that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  First part of code was by Mike Muller and I figured
out the second part from his comments.  This is a way in python to 
name a dictionary using variables.
    step = 1435
    d = {}
    for start in range(0, len(l), step):
        end = start + step
        part = l[start:end]
        d[tuple(part[2:4])] = part
    uu=1
    vari = {}
    for x in range(1,12):
        for y in range(1,15):
            if (str(x),str(y)) in d:
                vari[uu] = d[str(x),str(y)][50]
                print(('key  ',x,y),('value  ',vari[uu]),('counter  ',uu))
                #check results
                uu=uu+1
    print('out of loop check  ', vari[87])                 # check results